# How to split a multiindex df in 80/20 parts based on date?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

In my df I have a multiindex like this:

```
df.index.names
FrozenList([u'Ticker', u'Date'])

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 189667 entries, (AAPL, 1992-08-31 00:00:00) to (^DJI, 2017-08-31 00:00:00)
```

On a single index df I would do:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
```

However, this does not work with multiindex, it just cuts the rows in 80/20.

Note: I do not want random sampling, just splitting 80/20 based on date.

Any clues?

**Edit:**

This is how I fetch the data in question (apart from many more than two tickers):

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

tickers = ['AAPL', 'AXP']

def get_data(tickers):
    ''' Dowloads daily O/H/L/C data for all symbols'''
    def data(ticker):
        return web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo')
    datas = map(data, tickers)
    return pd.concat(datas, keys=tickers, names=['Ticker', 'Date'])

stock_data = get_data(tickers)
```

Comment: i'm having a hard time trying to reproduce it. Can you provide a small reproducible data set and your desired data sets?

Comment: @MaxU please see above

Comment: and what is your desired data sets?

Comment: a df stock_data_train with 80% of the earlier dates per ticker and stock_data_test with the last 20% dates per ticker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way of doing so:
first get the test group by groupby ticker(index level 0) then sorting each resulting group by date (descending order) then getting the first 20% of the data using selection

```
df_test = stock_data.groupby(level=0).apply(
    lambda group: group.sort_index(
        ascending=False).iloc[:int(len(group) * .2)]
).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

df_train will be all the records in `stock_data` and not in df_test, we can get df_train using boolean masking on the multiple index

```
df_train = stock_data[~stock_data.index.isin(df_test.index)]
```

alternatively using the same code for df_test where .2 is replaced by ,8 and `ascending=False` is replaced by `ascending=True`